# Cannot install PyQt5 on PyCharm

Tags: python, terminal, pyqt5

I get this error each time I try to install PyQt5 on PyCharm

[image: Error]

So I try running the executed command from the system terminal as suggested in the screenshot and get this.

`zsh: command not found: pip`

I use this this command instead

`python3 -m pip install PyQt5`

and it shows as already installed

However, in PyCharm, PyQt5 is still undetected.

Comment: I am trying through IntelliJ now and I get this issue: "Installing packages into 'Python 3.8' requires administrator privileges". I have macOS

Comment: Did you try using the `Python Packages` tab in Pycharm? (it's along the bottom of the window)

Answer (score 0):

enter the following code in your terminal

"pip install pyqt5 pyqt5-tools"

Test if pqyt5 is actually installed
Create a new file, example.py, and enter the following code.

```
import sys    
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore  

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()  
widget.resize(400, 200)  
widget.setWindowTitle("This is PyQt Widget example")  
widget.show()        
exit(app.exec_())
```

Read this Article below I think it's very helpful that's is where i got my knowledge
https://pythonpyqt.com/how-to-install-pyqt5-in-pycharm/

Comment: I tried `pip3 install pyqt5 pyqt5-tools` and it gave me loads of error and got stuck on "loading metadata". When I try `python3 -m pip install PyQt5`, it states that it's already installed. I looked for the package and found that it was installed in a folder named Python3.9 while my IDE install packages to a folder named Python3.8, I'm not sure what that means but I'm guessing it's related to the issue.

Comment: I managed to somehow install PyQt5 and other dependent packages; however, when I run the code you provided me, I get this error: `(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/QtWidgets.abi3.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/QtWidgets.abi3.so' (no such file)`